# Maintaining sequence of the read files in a directory with python

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to loop through the csv files in a directory so that they are read in the same sequence as stored in the directory. I am aware of the methods like using  *os.walk* or *os.listdir*. To preserve the sequence I used a *sorted(os.listdir..)* but the sequence is still not the same. I have attached two images for ease of understanding. I do not want to change the names of the files now because this data was generated from different simulation software. [image: files stored in the directory]

[image: files read by python]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this statement: sorted(os.listdir(dir_unresolved),key=len)